# Convert R object(Dataframe) to Pandas Dataframe using rpy2

Tags: pandas, rpy2

Iam using rpy2 to get comorbidity Index of patients , i got the results but iam not able to convert those output to  pandas Dataframe
below is the code

```
      #creating Datframe
data = {"person_id":[1,1,1,2,2,3],
             "dx_1":["F11","E40","","F32","C77","G10"],
             "dx_2":["F1P","E400","","F322","C737",""]}

#converting Pandas Dataframe to R Datframe using rpy2
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

r_dataframe = pandas2ri.py2ri(df1)
print(r_dataframe)

#installing  'comorbidity ' package using rpy2

R = rpy2.robjects.r
DTW = importr('comorbidity')

#executing comorbidity function by using one column icd_1 

output = DTW.comorbidity(x = r_dataframe, id = "person_id", code = "icd_1", 
                         score = "charlson", assign0 = False,
                         icd = "icd10")

print(output)
```

but not able to convert output to pandas dataframe

```
import rpy2, rpy2.robjects as robjects, rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
#Converting data frames back and forth between rpy2 and pandas
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
 #convert output to pandas dataframe
 pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(output)
```

getting below error

TypeError: Parameter 'categories' must be list-like, was

please help
Thanks in advance